# How do I perform a rotation animation on top of a base angle other than 0?

Tags: javascript, css, animation, css-animations

In JS I have some code that transform rotates the heads of my three sprites to follow the cursor on the screen. Additionally, I have a CSS keyframe animation I made to sort of "rattle the heads". My issue is, that this animation uses what seems to be a datum of `0deg` and I want it to instead use the current angle with the mouse as the centre.

I have this value as `angle1`, 2, 3, in JS but not in CSS. Is there a way to use this angle in CSS? So instead my animation would do something like transform: `rotate(baseAngle + 90)` etc? See below for SC.

I also a feel a gif of the behaviour is pretty valuable here:
https://gyazo.com/90855776c7803c63b72d378cb4a3c194

JS for tracking mouse movement:

```
(function() {
    document.onmousemove = handleMouseMove;
    function handleMouseMove(event) {
        var scrollMaxY, dot, eventDoc, doc, body, pageX, pageY;

        // IE-isms
        event = event || window.event;
        maxY = window.innerHeight || (document.documentElement.innerHeight - document.documentElement.clientHeight)

        // If pageX/Y aren't available and clientX/Y are,
        if (event.pageX == null && event.clientX != null) {
            eventDoc = (event.target && event.target.ownerDocument) || document;
            doc = eventDoc.documentElement;
            body = eventDoc.body;

            event.pageX = event.clientX +
              (doc && doc.scrollLeft || body && body.scrollLeft || 0) -
              (doc && doc.clientLeft || body && body.clientLeft || 0);
            event.pageY = event.clientY +
              (doc && doc.scrollTop  || body && body.scrollTop  || 0) -
              (doc && doc.clientTop  || body && body.clientTop  || 0 );
        }

        // TODO: Use x/y values to rotate heads
        angle1 = Math.atan2( event.pageY - head1[0], event.pageX - head1[1]);
        angle2 = Math.atan2( event.pageY - head2[0], event.pageX - head2[1]);
        angle3 = Math.atan2( event.pageY - head3[0], event.pageX - head3[1]);
        $("#kodama-head1").css("transform", "rotate(" + angle1 + "rad)");
        $("#kodama-head2").css("transform", "rotate(" + angle2 + "rad)");
        $("#kodama-head3").css("transform", "rotate(" + angle3 + "rad)");
    }
})();
```

My CSS keyframes animation:

```
@keyframes RattleHeads {
    0% {
        transform: rotate(90deg);
        -webkit-transition: all 600ms cubic-bezier(0.075, 0.82, 0.165, 1);
        transition: all 600ms cubic-bezier(0.075, 0.82, 0.165, 1);
    }
    55% {
        transform: rotate(-60deg);
    }
    69% {
        transform: rotate(45deg);
    }
    78% {
        transform: rotate(-30deg);
    }
    85% {
        transform: rotate(20deg);
    }
    91% {
        transform: rotate(-15deg);
    }
    95% {
        transform: rotate(10deg);
    }
    98% {
        transform: rotate(-5deg);
    }
    100% {
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
}
```

Lastly, the JS being used to apply rattling animation:

```
$("body").click(function(){
    var KodamaHead;
    var random = Math.random() * 3;
    if (random > 2){
        KodamaHead = $("#kodama-head3");        
    }
    else if (random > 1){
        KodamaHead = $("#kodama-head2");
    }
    else{
        KodamaHead = $("#kodama-head1");
    }
    // add animation
    KodamaHead.addClass("rattling");
    // remove animation on completion
    KodamaHead.one("webkitAnimationEnd oanimationend oAnimationEnd msAnimationEnd animationend",   
    function(e) {
        $(this).removeClass("rattling");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply wrap your head element inside an other element.
The transform of the inner element will now be relative to the one of the wrapper.

In the following example, we apply the mouse driven rotation to the inner `.head` elements, while applying the CSS driven one (onclick) on the `.wrapper` elements.
Since here both share the same transform-origin , it could also have been done the other way around.

```js
$("body").click(function() {

  var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
  // Target one of the `.wrapper` elements
  var KodamaHead = $('.persona .wrapper').eq(random);
  // add animation
  KodamaHead.addClass("rattling");
  // remove animation on completion
  KodamaHead.one("webkitAnimationEnd oanimationend oAnimationEnd msAnimationEnd animationend",
    function(e) {
      $(this).removeClass("rattling");
    });
});


(function() {
  // get Elements rotation anchor
  var head1 = getAnchor('#kodama-head1');
  var head2 = getAnchor('#kodama-head2');
  var head3 = getAnchor('#kodama-head3');

  document.onmousemove = handleMouseMove;

  function handleMouseMove(event) {

    // removed some backward compatibility fluffs
    // feel free to add it back

    // calculations were off by half a π
    angle1 = Math.atan2(event.pageY - head1[0], event.pageX - head1[1]) - Math.PI / 2;
    angle2 = Math.atan2(event.pageY - head2[0], event.pageX - head2[1]) - Math.PI / 2;
    angle3 = Math.atan2(event.pageY - head3[0], event.pageX - head3[1]) - Math.PI / 2;
    $("#kodama-head1").css("transform", "rotate(" + angle1 + "rad)");
    $("#kodama-head2").css("transform", "rotate(" + angle2 + "rad)");
    $("#kodama-head3").css("transform", "rotate(" + angle3 + "rad)");
  }
})();

// get anchor position (center, center)
function getAnchor(sel) {
  var el = document.querySelector(sel),
    rect = el.getBoundingClientRect();
  return [rect.top + rect.height / 2, rect.left + rect.width / 2];
}
```

```css
.rattling {
  animation: RattleHeads 2s linear;
}

.persona {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 90vh;
  width: 20vw;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.head {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 20vw;
  width: 20vw;
  border: 1px solid;
  position: relative;
}

.head::before,
.head::after {
  content: '•';
  color: white;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 12px;
  width: 2vmax;
  height: 2vmin;
  position: absolute;
  top: 5vw;
  left: 7vw;
  background: black;
  border-radius: 20%;
}

.head::after {
  left: auto;
  right: 7vw;
}

@keyframes RattleHeads {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  55% {
    transform: rotate(-60deg);
  }
  69% {
    transform: rotate(45deg);
  }
  78% {
    transform: rotate(-30deg);
  }
  85% {
    transform: rotate(20deg);
  }
  91% {
    transform: rotate(-15deg);
  }
  95% {
    transform: rotate(10deg);
  }
  98% {
    transform: rotate(-5deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="persona">
  <div class="wrapper"><!-- rattling -->
    <div id="kodama-head1" class="head"><!-- look-at -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="persona">
  <div class="wrapper"><!-- rattling -->
    <div id="kodama-head2" class="head"><!-- look-at -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="persona">
  <div class="wrapper"><!-- rattling -->
    <div id="kodama-head3" class="head"><!-- look-at -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Damn that's clever, I really appreciate the effort you put into this. I ended up wrapping a div around my <img> elements for the heads and performing the CSS animation on that.